# Exclude material fonts from flutter web release

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I'm currently developing a flutter web application.
I notice that the application takes a lot of time to load (an average of 20 seconds).

[image: Here is a picture of what is taking so long.]

The fetch of the 'FontManifest.json' and the fonts 'MaterialIcons-Regular.otf' and 'CupertinoIcons.tff' takes an average of 10 seconds.
I'm not using any of these fonts, as I installed google fonts. It's just wasting time and data.

**My question is: how can I get rid of these two fonts in flutter web or how can I reduce the time of waiting tffb + content downloading?**

- I tried to edit the 'FontManifest.json' and remove the '.otf' and '.tff' but as the files are auto generated, flutter rewrite them during each build.
- I don't want to set use-material-design to false because i need some other features.
- I already tried to edit the 'fonts' field of the 'pubspec.yaml' file, it doesn't work.
- I have already read a few posts, but the questions mostly concerns display problems.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Hi Nagual, as said in the post above: 'I don't want to set use-material-design to false because i need some other features.'. I have not tried yet to remove cupertino_icons for the same reason, I will probably need it as the application is destined to have an iOS version. Even if I delete the Cupertino part, the problem will remain the same because the FontManifest and the MaterialIcons will be still there.

Answer (score 4):

There is a way instead to possibly optimize the build time of the other packages by using the command

```
cp -r ./build/app/intermediates/flutter/release/flutter_assets/ ./build/web/assets
```

and the treeshake function available by flutter

```
--tree-shake-icons
```

you can read more [here](https://medium.com/@GSYTech/how-to-optimize-flutter-web-and-how-flutter-web-work-in-html-renderer-b399ffd66718)

Comment: there are a lot of useful information in the link you've provided, thanks you solved my problem :)

Comment: i am unable to do that. how to implement it?